# Python: Extract the indices of repeated rows corresponding to the non-zero unique rows in a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

For this matrix K=

```
 [[1.  2.  3.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

How to store the list/array of indices of repeated rows corresponding to the non-zero unique rows in a matrix.

In this example:[0,2] are the indices of non-zero unique rows.

Question: How to store this information in a dictionary:

```
   corresponding value for key 0: [0]
   corresponding value for key 2: [2,4]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method via `collections.defaultdict`. It iterates via a `for` loop with `enumerate` and uses `set` to track seen items.

You can easily remove `(0, 0, 0)` from the dictionary at the end, and rename keys if necessary. The method is O(n) in complexity.

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = np.array([[ 1,  2,  3],
              [ 0,  0,  0],
              [ 4,  5,  6],
              [ 0,  0,  0],
              [ 4,  5,  6],
              [ 0,  0,  0]])

seen = {(0, 0, 0)}
d = defaultdict(list)

for idx, row in enumerate(map(tuple, A)):
    d[row].append(idx)
```

Result:

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list, {(0, 0, 0): [1, 3, 5],
                   (1, 2, 3): [0],
                   (4, 5, 6): [2, 4]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your data is in a list of tuples.

```
data = [
  (1, 2, 3),
  (0, 0, 0),
  (4, 5, 6),
  (0, 0, 0),
  (4, 5, 6),
  (0, 0, 0),
  ]
```

**Edit in response to comments:**

Invert the data into a default dict, appending the index onto the list that is attached to each key in the dict.

```
import collections
output = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i,v in enumerate(data):
  if v == (0,0,0):
    continue
  output[v].append(i)
print(output.values())
```

Output is:

```
[[0], [2, 4]]
```

**Original**

A simple loop will do.  This will

- ignore `(0,0,0)`
- record the index of the first instance of any sequential set of duplicates

It stores the indexes in a `set()` for performance, but sorts them at the end.

```
output = set()
lastval = None
lasti = None

for i, val in enumerate(data):
  if val == (0,0,0):
    continue

  if val != lastval:
    lastval = val
    lasti = i

  if lasti not in output:
    output.add(lasti)

print(sorted(output))
```

Output is

```
[0, 2]
```

Comment: Not sure what that means @ManiKumar

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. The output should be: with zero index, there is no other similar row so the corresponding list should be [0] and for the index 2, row 2 and row 4 are similar, so we get the list [2,4].